# Error Found When Loading /etc/profile Line 38:8.0_121 & 45:20.0_121 Command Not Found

Tags: login-screen

Error occurred when loading `/etc/profile`

```
/etc/profile:line 38:8.0_121 Command Not Found
/etc/profile:line 45:20.0_121 Command Not Found
As a result the session with be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem.
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the contents of the file /etc/profile . It seems that there is an incorrect commmand, but without reading is impossible to fix it. You could see it with:

```
cat /etc/profile
```

or

```
nano /etc/profile
```

Posted as an answer because I can't make comments :\